# How to extract cell values in one worksheet with corresponding numbers so that they line up by the same numbers in another worksheet in excel?

Tags: excel

I have some time values in one worksheet - sheet 1- for the numbers

101  09:00

102  09:10

103  09:15

The same numbers 101-103 appear in another worksheet - sheet 2- of the same Excel workbook, but they may be repetitive.

101

101

101

102

102

102

103

103

103

How can I use a formula to match the times from `sheet 1` to the numbers in `sheet 2` when they are repeating instead of copying them manually?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems that VLOOKUP is what you need.

Comment: Thanks!, does the syntax allow for sheet references, i am unable to find any examples

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VLOOKUP function for this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:B,2,0)
```

Comment: Thanks chris mack.